# как из консоли добавить строку в список по индексу?

Tags: java, switch, case

есть некий список дел

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>(){{
            add(0,"Почистить зубы");
            add(1,"Сделать зарядку");
            add(2,"Выпить стакан воды");
            add(3,"Приготовить завтрак");
            add(4,"Отправится на работу");
        }};
```

когда к нему добавляю новую строку из консоли, то ввожу ADD и "добавляю дело"

```
case "ADD":
    System.out.println("Добавить дело в список: ");
    todoList.add(sc.next());
    System.out.println("Дело добавлено!" + "номер в списке: " + todoList.size())
```

проблема в том, что нужно, чтобы строка добавлялась к списку и по индексу тоже (ADD 4 - "какое-то дело на четвёртом месте").
я понимаю, что это можно сделать через if и разделить строку на слова. и если первое слово - число, то использовать его для добавления в список "по индексу".
но не знаю как это реализовать в коде.
буду весьма признателен за любую помощь!

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Как распарсить строку? Придумайте в каком формате пользователь должен вводить данные. Например  `5,Название`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так. Например пользователь вводит строку 5,Название.

По тексту вы ищите первую запятую в тексте, делается это с помощью метода indexOf(","). Если получили индекс больше нуля - смотрите часть до запятой число или нет. Потом проверяете, если это число отрицательное или больше текущей длины списка добавляете в конец, иначе добавляете по индексу.

```
 String str = sc.next();
 int idx = str.indexOf(",");
 if( idx > 0 ){
     String strNum = str.substring(0, idx); 
     try{
         int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
         if( num > 0 && num < todoList.size() ){
             String val = str.substring(idx + 1, str.length - 1 );
             todoList.add( num, val );
         } else{
             todoList.add( val );
         }
     } catch(Exception e){
         todoList.add( str );
     }
 }else{
     todoList.add( str );
 }
```

Comment: Логику я понял. а как это написать?

Comment: Примерно так. Добавил код в ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое! а если эту строку удалить из списка или редактировать, то можно делать по этому же принципу?

Comment: чтоб удалить из списка вам достаточно только индекса todoList.remove(idx); А редактирование я так понимаю это будет удаление и добавление в тот же индекс

Comment: премного благодарен! вы очень помогли!

Comment: Спасибо здесь принято говорить стрелками слева от ответа :) Обращайтесь еще.

Answer (score 0):

Если пользователь введет -1, то элемент вставится просто в конец

```
int num, flag;
String text = sc.next();
flag = text.indexOf(',');
try {
num = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, flag));
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
num = -1;
}
if (num >= 0) {
todoList.add(num, text.substring(flag + 1)); // +1 так как после запятой пробел
}
if (num < 0 && flag >= 0) {
todoList.add(text.substring(flag + 1));
}
if (num < 0 && flag < 0) {
todoList.add(text);
}
```

Вроде все, будут вопросы по коду - задавайте.

Comment: опередили -_- ....