# Как в заполненный arraylist добавлять новые элементы по определенному индексу?

Tags: java, arraylist

Например, существует список и надо добавить в его начало и конец знак `"-"` и вывести его в строку.  Существует ли метод, чтобы добавлять элементы по любому индексу?

Comment: [`public void add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-)

Comment: См. [как из консоли добавить строку в список по индексу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077159/) (2020)

Answer (score 1):

Как отмечено в комментариях, для добавления элемента в список по нужному индексу существует метод, определённый в *интерфейсе `List`*: [`List::add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-).
Для добавления элемента в конец списка достаточно пользоваться стандартным [`List::add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-).
Однако для добавления *символов* (строк) `"-"` в заданный список он также должен содержать символы или строки.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
list.add(0, "-"); // в начало
list.add("-");    // в конец
System.out.println(list); // [-, a, b, c, -]
// просто через пробел
System.out.println(String.join(" ", list)); // - a b c -
```

---

Поэтому основная задача выглядит скорее как *вывести строку из списка* с символами `"-"` в начале и конце, и для её решения совершенно не требуется модифицировать сам входной список.

Достаточно добавлять нужные символы к *строке*, полученной из списка, для чего существует масса способов:

- простая конкатенация, строка из списка получена при помощи `List::toString`

```java
public static <T> String listToString(List<T> list) {
    return "-" + list + "-";
}

System.out.println(listToString(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
// -[1, 2, 3]-
```

- Для произвольного списка: коллектор `Collectors.joining` с делимитером и префиксом/суффиксом:

```java
public static <T> String join(List<T> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "-", "-")); // делимитер, префикс/суффикс
}

System.out.println(join(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))); // любой тип
// -1 2 3-
```

- Для входного списка *строк*: `StringBuilder` + `String::join` с делимитером

```java
public static String sbAndJoin(List<CharSequence> list) {
    return new StringBuilder()
        .append("-")
        .append(String.join(" ", list)) // через пробел
        .append("-")
        .toString();
}

System.out.println(sbAndJoin(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"))); // строки!
// -1 2 3-
```